# Javascript if/else syntax errors

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic

Getting syntax error on my else statement Ive rewritten the code and pasted from known good statements. What am I missing? Its supposed to just check math.random and compare in an if/else

```html
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice =< .33)
{
    computerChoice = "Rock";
}

else if (computerChoice > .33 && computerChoice =< .66)
{
    computerChoice = "Paper";
}

else
{
    computerChoice = "Scissors";
}
```

Comment: put a zero in front of the decimal places. if (computerChoice =< .33)

Comment: you got your logical operator the wrong way round. it should be <= not =< you could always just use real fractions, because they are evaluated to floats with the maximum number of decimal places, i.e. `if(computerChoice < 1/3){}elseif(computerChoice > 2/3){}else{}` Math.random() uses the same number of decimal places as 1/3 or 2/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of quick fixes:

Use a 0 in front of all the decimals
use `<=` instead of `=<`

Those are the only fixes I made, I saw them the second I pasted them in a JSBin

[JsBin with corrected code](https://jsbin.com/mivepeh/1/edit?js,console)

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice <= 0.33)
{
    computerChoice = "Rock";
}

else if (computerChoice > 0.33 && computerChoice <= 0.66)
{
    computerChoice = "Paper";
}

else
{
    computerChoice = "Scissors";
}
```

Comment: That did it I have been teaching myself javascript Id have never thought to check the operators like that THANKS!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors");    
var choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]; 
var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (choices.length-1)); 
computerChoice = choices[rand];
```

Something like this could work.

Comment: You are right, i should add a Math.round around it :)

Comment: `var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * choices.length );`

Comment: Math.round return a more balanced random number

Comment: `Math.round(Math.random() * choices.length);` can return a number from 0 to 3 but the only valid indices here are 0 to 2

Comment: `Math.round(Math.random() * (choices.length - 1));` should do the trick then!

Answer (score 0):

You got your logical operator the wrong way round. it should be `<=` not `=<`.

Anyway, the IF THEN ELSE isn't really necessary here, and although other answers are on the right track, there is no need to count how many elements in the array. There are always going to be 3 possible outcomes in this game:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors");
var computerChoice = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
```